# XSl: whitespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace

I need to make sure that the whitespaces of my inline XML elements have the whitespaces around them, and not inside them :

```
some text <i>text in italic</i> some text
```

and not

```
some text<i> text in italic </i>some text
or some text<i> text in italic</i> some text
or some text <i>text in italic </i> some text
```

And that some elements (paragraphes, titles) do not have whitespaces after the opening tag or before the closing tag:

```
<p>some text</p>
```

and not

```
<p> some text</p><!--or-->
<p> some text </p><!--or-->
<p> some text</p>
```

I tried xsl:strip-space on the following XML:

```
<book>
<appendix>
    <title>T<pc>itre</pc></title>
    <subtitle> <i> some text </i> </subtitle>
    <dev>
    <sect1>
    <title>R<pc>ésumé </pc></title>
    <p> some text</p>
        <sect2>
            <title>S<pc>ome text</pc></title>
            <p> some text </p>
            <p> some text</p>
        </sect2>
</sect1>
</dev>
</appendix>
```

but I do not quite understand how it works (on some elements it seems to work and not on others - works for subtitles but not for p-s with <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>). And I know it would not solve my problem with inline elements. Is there any way to do this in XSLT ? I can see how I could find the spaces in inline elements with regex but not how to place them outside the element afterwards.

Thank you.
Maria

Comment: Whitespace stripping affects only text nodes that contain only whitespace characters.  You need to use the `normalize-space()` function.

Comment: Thank you! As normalize-space() takes strings as arguments and I may have other types of nodes, it is probably better not to do this in XSLT?

Comment: You can make a template that matches text() nodes within specified parent.

Comment: good idea, thank you!

Comment: I should add that **removing** leading/trailing whitespace from inner nodes is easy; **moving** them to the parent node is not.